# How to include html templates with angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a html fragement that should lateron serve as an image slider. So far it only contains a test div element:

```
slider.html:
<div>TEST</div>
```

I'm trying to include this in my `index.html` as follows:

```
<div ng-include src="slider.html"></div>
```

Result: I don't see the test div. Why?

Comment: ng-include="'slider.html'"

Comment: @ajmajmajma You need to put single quotes around the string constant.

Comment: Already answered here:<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31609423/5052704


Hope this helps.

Comment: Already answered here 
<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31609423/5052704


Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div ng-include="'slider.html'"></div>
```

When using a path in `ng-include` you need to enclose it with single quotes, since it expects an expression.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude):

> If the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in single
>   quotes, e.g. src="'myPartialTemplate.html'".

Comment: @membersound don't forget to mark a given answer as answered

Answer (score 1):

```
<ng-include src="'slider.html'"></ng-include>
```

or

```
<div ng-include src="'slider.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include another html like below:

```
<div ng-include src = "'partials/myModule/myHtml.html'"></div>
```

It has already been answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31609423/5052704

Hope this helps.